# Save screen recording in mp4 format in macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, screen-capture

Using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> records screen nicely, but the output video is in Mov format, which makes it not playable (stream playing) in Google Chrome.

Is there a way to make it output video in Mp4?

Transcoding Mov to Mp4 is quite time-consuming.

Comment: Mods, please consider linking this question to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164655/export-mov-to-mp4-with-quicktime-on-yosemite

Comment: No, MacOS Mojave's screen capture application as well as QuickTime does not allow you to save directly to MP4, unfortunately. Either use a 3rd party utility or convert the `.mov` file into `.mp4` , e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mp4`